# Text file Side by Side Merge not working via Bat file

Tags: csv, batch-file, merge

To merge two csv file side by side, I used this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< ..\Data\2.csv (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (..\Data\1.csv) do (
      set /P line2=
      echo %%a,!line2!
   )
) > ..\Data\input.csv
```

It worked fine on two small csv files, eg:

```
File 1
------
a     
b     
File 2
------
apple 
ball
```

But when I tried to merge these two csv files,
File 1:

```
source,hcid,fname,lname,dob,gender,relTpCd,Rel
WGS20,902A07430,Subs,Performancel,1965-07-01,F,SCRBR,Subscriber
WGS20,686T08408,Abdullah,Wilson,1965-01-01,F,SCRBR,Subscriber
WGS20,265A06410,Aewae,Asfwafc,1974-11-18,M,SCRBR,Subscriber
```

File 2:

```
SLangCd,SLang,SLangDesc,WLangC
100,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,English,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
100,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,English,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
100449,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
```

I am getting a merged file like this (lines of File 2 getting printed alone:

```
source,hcid,fname,lname,dob,gender,relTpCd,Rel,SLangCd,SLang,SLangDesc,WLangC
WGS20,902A07430,Subs,Performancel,1965-07-01,F,SCRBR,Subscriber,100,SPOKEN     LANGUAGE,English,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
100,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,English,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
100449,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
WGS20,686T08408,Abdullah,Wilson,1965-01-01,F,SCRBR,Subscriber,100,SPOKEN     LANGUAGE,English,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
100,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,English,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
100449,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
WGS20,265A06410,Aewae,Asfwafc,1974-11-18,M,SCRBR,Subscriber,100,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,English,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
100,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,English,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
100449,SPOKEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined,100449,WRITTEN LANGUAGE,Undetermined
```

Comment: After doing: echo !line2!
it shows that !line2! is storing whole content of the second file and not only a single line from second file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files have a single LF (line feed, `0x0A` character) as line termination, instead of CRLF (carriage return, '0x0D 0x0A` characters) standard line terminators in windows.

While the `for /f` command is able to handle it, the redirected `set /p` will retrieve everything up to the first CR or 1021 characters, what happens first.

You will need to process (at least) the `2.csv` file with something like

```
type 2.csv | find /v "" > 2.csv.tmp
```

that will generate a temporary file with the correct line termination. This is the file that you should use as redirected input.